# Numeric.AD and typing problem

Tags: haskell, types, automatic-differentiation

I'm trying to work with Numeric.AD and a custom Expr type. I wish to calculate
the symbolic gradient of user inputted expression.  The first trial with a constant
expression works nicely:

```
calcGrad0 :: [Expr Double]
calcGrad0 = grad df vars
  where
   df [x,y] = eval (env [x,y]) (EVar "x"*EVar "y")
   env vs = zip varNames vs
   varNames = ["x","y"]
   vars = map EVar varNames
```

This works:

```
>calcGrad0
[Const 0.0 :+ (Const 0.0 :+ (EVar "y" :* Const 1.0)),Const 0.0 :+ (Const 0.0 :+ (EVar "x" :* Const 1.0))]
```

However, if I pull the expression out as a parameter:

```
calcGrad1 :: [Expr Double]
calcGrad1 = calcGrad1' (EVar "x"*EVar "y")
calcGrad1' e = grad df vars
  where
   df [x,y] = eval (env [x,y]) e
   env vs = zip varNames vs
   varNames = ["x","y"]
   vars = map EVar varNames
```

I get

```
Could not deduce (a ~ AD s (Expr a1))
from the context (Num a1, Floating a)
  bound by the inferred type of
           calcGrad1' :: (Num a1, Floating a) => Expr a -> [Expr a1]
  at Symbolics.hs:(60,1)-(65,29)
or from (Mode s)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             Mode s => [AD s (Expr a1)] -> AD s (Expr a1)
  at Symbolics.hs:60:16-27
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the inferred type of
      calcGrad1' :: (Num a1, Floating a) => Expr a -> [Expr a1]
      at Symbolics.hs:60:1
Expected type: [AD s (Expr a1)] -> AD s (Expr a1)
  Actual type: [a] -> a
In the first argument of `grad', namely `df'
In the expression: grad df vars
```

How do I get ghc to accept this?

Comment: This got solved by Saizan at #haskell already. I was just missing fmap lift e in the call to eval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you are forgetting to apply [lift](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ad/1.0.6/doc/html/Numeric-AD-Mode-Mixed.html#v:lift) to convert an `Expr` to an `AD s Expr`.

If you are interested in using the [ad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) package for symbolic differentiation. Lennart Augustsson's [traced](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/traced) package works well.

Answer (score 1):

When GHC cannot deduce a type equality signature for a valid function, as in your case, the solution is to give the function a type signature.  I do not know the interface to this library.  However, my guess is that the correct signature is `calcGrad1 :: (Num a, Floating a) => Expr a -> [Expr a]`.