# Acceptable types in Numeric.AD functions

Tags: haskell, types, automatic-differentiation, constraint-kinds

I'm having little success wrapping my head around the basic plumbing of the types involved in the `ad` package.  For example, the following works perfectly:

```
import Numeric.AD

ex :: Num a => [a] -> a
ex [x, y] = x + 2*y

> grad ex [1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 2.0]
```

where `grad` has the type:

```
grad
  :: (Num a, Traversable f) =>
     (forall (s :: * -> *). Mode s => f (AD s a) -> AD s a)
     -> f a -> f a
```

If I change the type signature of `ex` to `[Double] -> Double` and try the same thing, I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `AD s a0' with actual type `Double'
Expected type: f0 (AD s a0) -> AD s a0
  Actual type: [Double] -> Double
```

The same behaviour occurs when replacing `Double` with seemingly any type constructor with kind `*` that instantiates `Num`.

When the `Traversable f` is a list, the first argument of `grad` must have type `[AD s a] -> AD s a` for some acceptable [`Mode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ad/3.0/doc/html/Numeric-AD-Types.html#t:Mode) - e.g., [`Reverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ad/3.0/doc/html/Numeric-AD-Internal-Reverse.html#t:Reverse).  But clearly the user of `grad` doesn't have to deal with the [`AD`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ad/3.0/doc/html/Numeric-AD-Types.html#t:AD) constructor or the `Mode` directly.  Peeking into these internals have left me a bit confused; specifically, I can't follow the kind/type trail to the difference between using `Num a => [a] -> a` and `[Double] -> Double`.

Why does the type signature `[Double] -> Double` cause problems with `grad`?  And in terms of plain old library use: is there any way to use the `[Double] -> Double` version of `ex`, or is a polymorphic version necessary?

(title inspired by [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938337/numeric-ad-and-typing-problem))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the `ad` library, but since `grad` expects a function of type `[AD s a] -> AD s a` as its first parameter, you cannot expect to be able to pass it a function of type `[Double] -> Double`, since `Double` and `AD` are completely different types.

The generic function with `Num` constraint works, because `AD` itself is also an instance of `Num`, therefore in your working example, `ex` gets specialized to something like

```
ex :: (Mode s, Fractional a) => [AD s a] -> AD s a
```

If you want to specialize `ex` for calculations using Doubles, you need to give it a signature such as

```
ex :: Mode s => [AD s Double] -> AD s Double
```

Comment: Ahhhh ok, so `AD` is an instance of `Num`.  I failed to notice that in the instances list, but I see it now.

Comment: Also, if you have some constants lying around as Doubles, say, in other data structures, you may need to use Numeric.AD.Types.lift or the other combinators in Mode to have them interact with your AD s Double arguments and result.