# How to properly match types when using Numeric.AD in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, forall, automatic-differentiation, rank-n-types

I'm trying to implement Newton–Raphson root-finding algorithm using the [ad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) package, but I can't properly match function types. I know there's [a proper answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938337/numeric-ad-and-typing-problem), which was answered by the creator of ad himself, but the package have changed greatly since version 1.0.6 (current version is 4.3.4).

This first minimum example compiles and works when I iterate over it:

```
import Numeric.AD
import Numeric.AD.Internal.Forward

g :: Fractional a => a -> a
g x = - x + 2

g' :: Fractional a => a -> a
g' x = diff g x

newtonG :: Fractional a => a -> a
newtonG x = x - (g x) / (g' x)
```

But if I try to abstract the function, like this:

```
import Numeric.AD
import Numeric.AD.Internal.Forward

g :: Fractional a => a -> a
g x = - x + 2

newton :: Fractional a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
newton f x = x - (f x) / (diff f x)
```

GHC returns the following error:

```
fsolve.hs:8:32: error:
    * Couldn't match type `a' with `AD s (Forward a)'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          newton :: forall a. Fractional a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
        at fsolve.hs:7:11
      Expected type: AD s (Forward a) -> AD s (Forward a)
        Actual type: a -> a
    * In the first argument of `diff', namely `f'
      In the second argument of `(/)', namely `(diff f x)'
      In the second argument of `(-)', namely `(f x) / (diff f x)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at fsolve.hs:8:10)
        f :: a -> a (bound at fsolve.hs:8:8)
        newton :: (a -> a) -> a -> a (bound at fsolve.hs:8:1)
```

If I use `Numeric.AD.Rank1.Forward` instead of `Numeric.AD`, the compiler says it cannot match `a` with `Forward a`, instead of `a` with `AD s (Forward a)`. I also tried several ways of creating a dual number from `x` to pass it to `f`, e.g. `snd . unbundle . f $ bundle x 1`, but it only works if I create a new `g' x` using it, like in first case. Using this within `newton` doesn't work either.

In `Numeric.AD`, `diff :: Num a => (forall s. AD s (Forward a) -> AD s (Forward a)) -> a -> a`. And in `Numeric.AD.Rank1.Forward`, it's `diff :: Num a => (Forward a -> Forward a) -> a -> a`. So why do they accept a function of type `a -> a` in the first case, but not in the second? Besides using polymorphic functions, should I take any special care when creating functions to use with `Numeric.AD`? Lastly, how should I change my code to make it work? I know the package [already has a function to find roots](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.3.4/docs/Numeric-AD-Rank1-Newton.html#g:1), but I don't want to use yet (since I'm still learning Haskell), and looking at the documentation trying to sort this out, felt like running in circles.

Comment: I can't remember if this has any significance on the top of my head, and i am unable to verify it aswell, and i also see that you discuss it briefly in your post, but try adding (Num a => a -> a) instead of (a -> a) as one of your arguments to newton. EDIT -- I just realized that it will infer the type of a as already Fractional aka Num, this comment will probably have no effect. I will keep looking at this, challange accepted.

Comment: Sounds like the first example uses `g` at two different types. To be able to do that with a function argument, you need rank-2 types: `newton :: Fractional a => (forall b. Fractional b => b -> b) -> a -> a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that your function:

```
newton :: Fractional a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
newton f x = x - (f x) / (diff f x)
```

uses the function argument `f` in two places.  First, the
subexpression `f x` uses `f` with the type:

```
f :: Fractional a => a -> a
```

Second, due to the use of `diff` the subexpression `diff f x` uses `f` with the type:

```
f :: forall s a. Fractional a => AD s (Forward a) -> AD s (Forward a)
```

The error message you got is the type system observing that these
are different types that cannot be unified.

The solution is to explicitly quantify the function argument of `newton`
to work for all types satisfying the appropriate numeric type class constraint(s).  This requires the `RankNTypes` language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newton
  :: Fractional a
  => (forall b. Fractional b => b -> b)
  -> a
  -> a
newton f x = x - (f x) / (diff f x)
```

Comment: If I just enable `RankNTypes`, will the compiler be able to infer the proper signature?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin GHC will never infer higher-ranks types. I think I heard that type checking using such types is an undecidable problem, so the user must provide some help. (I don't have a reference for that, though)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I guess my next topic is learning about `RankNTypes`.